# unitary transformation without two matrix multiplications

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Hi Math StackExchange.

Is there an efficient algorithm that accomplishes a unitary transformation $U^{T}AU$ of a symmetric real-valued matrix $A$ without two *independent* matrix multiplications? To clarify, I am not diagonalizing - I am not interested in getting the eigenvectors/values of $A$, just in rotating the basis of $A$ using $U$. $U$ consists of $N$ mutually orthogonal and normalized column vectors that are the eigenvectors for some matrix that is not $A$. Is there a shortcut to do this?